# Unobtrusive Method for Instantiating Socket Object from File Descriptor

Tags: c++, python, sockets, dll, file-descriptor

There currently exists a socket library in Python:

**Reference**: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html

However, this library does not include functionality for referencing an existing socket based off a file descriptor. I am currently developing Python bindings for a C++ library which opens up a socket first and need a way to reference this opened socket in Python after-the-fact. **Keep in mind that this is on Windows** (I am using a cross-platform layer of abstraction which neglects file handles).

The code is similar to this:

```
fd = connect(...) # file descriptor
os.read(fd, buffer)
os.close(fd)
```

I am looking to find a way to actually define a socket object based off the file descriptor without the by-value duplication found in `os.dup` and `os.dup2`.

Would anyone know a way to reference this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it doesn't appear that this question has been answered as of yet (for 1 week), I'll state my solution.

I implemented an internal binding for retrieving the socket information from within the library, converting the `ctypes` to `pytuples`. Because the application itself is wrapped in `py2exe`, this modification is unobtrusive to the end-user.

Answer (score 0):

Please check again:

http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.fromfd

Comment: Windows has file descriptors? Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`socket.fromfd(fd, family, type[, proto])` seems to do what you want.  It's only available on Unix like platforms, unfortunately.

Unfortunately, this functionality does not seem to be available for Windows.  You may consider logging a bug at http://bugs.python.org/ (I see no reason why a windows socket object should not be wrappable in a Python socket object).

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  You can use it to wrap sockets and/or file descriptors, so that they feel more like files, while providing operations useful in framing data like sock.readto('\0'):

```
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/bufsock.html
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. I cannot instantiate a socket with simply the fd.